# prevent a variable form being edited by child based on condition

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

```
class AppController extends Controller {

/**
 * @var $IsAjax weather request is ajax or not
 */
public $RequestType = 'NORMAL'; //make this read only by child

    function __construct() 
    {
      if(isAjax())
        $RequestType ='AJAX'; 
        $layout = 'ajax'; //this var should not be editable further i.e read only by child
    }

}
```

If request is ajax I want it not to be editable. If it fails `$layout` should be editable by children.

Also is there a way to make the variable `readonly` for child.

Comment: what does your ajax request have to do with "weather"? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to get readOnly properties is to set their visibility to private and then use magic methods __get and __set to access them. for ex:

```
class A{
  private $readOnly = 'readOnly';
  function __get($key){
    if( $key === 'readonly')
      return $this->{$key};
  }
}
```

then readonly may be accessible for reading by anyone but only the A class may write to it

Answer (score 1):

You can control access to the member variable though set/get methods and make the variable private:

```
class ParentClass
{
    private $requestType = "Normal";

    protected function getRequestType()
    {
        return $this->requestType;
    }

    protected function setRequestType( $newType )
    {
        if ( $this->requestType != "AJAX" )
        {
            $this->requestType = $newType;
        }
    }
};
```